# Molecular Script Add-on: Why does this particle system explodes?

Tags: particles

[image]

This particle system with Molecular Add-on explodes even though there seems to be more than enough space between the particles.

frame 2

[image]

frame 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you still turned on the normal velocity:

[image]

change it to zero and it works.

by the way: whenever physics / simulation is going on you should apply your scale...which you didn't for your instance cube.